# CodeIgniter not storing sessions in IE

Tags: codeigniter, internet-explorer, session

I am using version 2.1.3 of CodeIgniter, and primarily use Chrome or FireFox, but I am learning that some of my clients are having issues with my systems not allowing them to log in. The system log indicates that the user has logged in, but I check if the session variable is set to determine whether the control panel or login screen needs to be displayed.

For some reason, the session variables are not set in at least IE8 and below, so the login screen keeps showing, even though the log says the user is logged in.

I checked this: [CodeIgniter IE not storing sessions correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850960/codeigniter-ie-not-storing-sessions-correctly) and this is not applicable to me.

I am not using Ajax for this, so this is not it either: [PHP Session lost in CodeIgniter IE only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686620/php-session-lost-in-codeigniter-ie-only)

Also, this is not loaded in an iFrame. So, I doubt there are P3P problems: [CodeIgniter 2.x sessions and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912168/codeigniter-2-x-sessions-and-internet-explorer)

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article, and it appears to solve the problem for me, but I want to test more before accepting my own answer.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/211955/#982986

Hope this helps someone else.

Regards,

Kobus

Answer (score 0):

I could just guess, hope its helpful.

Check your php files if you have a closing tag ?> and if you have a whitespace after it. This cause to return a blank response, because of the whitespace, and this breaks the session and cookies.

Do you have some mechanism for regenerating session id`s

Thats all i can come up with, hope i`ve helped.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, gprusiiski. I checked your suggestion, and did not have any whitespace problems. See my own answer below, although I do not want to accept it yet, as I still want to test it for a few more days.